# Android java : Error on SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

Am a beginner at android java.

Error on `SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();` line in

```
public boolean deleteItem(Todomodel todomodel){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); //HERE
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    int numb = todomodel.getId();
    String whereClause = "id=?";
    String whereArgs[] = {String.valueOf(numb)};
    db.delete("CUSTOMER_TABLE", whereClause, whereArgs);
    db.close();

    return false;
}
```

ERROR :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.monday, PID: 9794
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.File android.content.Context.getDatabasePath(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getDatabasePath(ContextWrapper.java:330)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:292)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:238)
        at com.example.monday.database.deleteItem(database.java:72)
```

I already had called the getWritabledatabase in the insert function.
But when I try to write again. It doesn't work.

Comment: check your database context if you are passing it,
check your read/write storage permissions,
check whether you are initialize or opening your database before performing query!

Comment: @M.BilalAsif I have checked various site and it all looked the same code. What you mean by passing the context. I have passed a model to the function and I get the correct output on the other side. and first time calling the database class I have passed the this.mainactivity..

Comment: okay have you check your database path this should be checked carefully!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a valid `Context` to your `SQLiteOpenHelper` constructor.

Comment: I have passed this.Mainactiviy to while creating a  object for the database class like I did for the insert function which works perfect.

Comment: The Context can still be invalid. Please post code around how you are contructing the db helper, and maybe also how you are calling that code.

Comment: yes it works! but to call the update list which holds the set adapter is now the task that is in which I can't pass the context to from the adapter